AzureWebApp@1 does not deploy to the site/wwwroot
I was trying to create a node js deployment to an Azure web app resource. However, AzureWebApp@1 does not deploy the zip file to the correct location, it just tells me it was successful.
my yaml file looks like this:
trigger:
- master

stages:
- stage:
  displayName: 'Dev Environment'
  jobs:
  - deployment: deploy_dev
    displayName: Deploy to 'Dev
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'env-dev'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout: self
            - script: |
                cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
                pwd
                ls
              displayName: show directory
            - script: npm install
              displayName: 'Install dependencies'
            - task: Npm@1
              inputs:
                command: 'custom'
                customCommand: 'run build'
            - task: ArchiveFiles@2
              inputs:
                rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build'
                includeRootFolder: false
                archiveType: 'zip'
                archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                replaceExistingArchive: true
            - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
              inputs:
                PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            - script: |
                unzip -l $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            - task: AzureWebApp@1
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: <subscription>
                appType: 'webAppLinux'
                appName: <appname>
                package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

I added some extra logging just for my sanity. All the right files are found within the zip file. When I download the artifact, it too contains all the correct files:

but once I go and check in the kudolite bash and enter into the site/wwwroot those files are nowhere to be found.

These appear to be just the default files for the default page Microsoft loads when a user creates a Linux node web app.
but yet AzureWebApp@1 claims to be successful. So something odd is happening, or I'm missing something obvious.

edit:
(updated now where the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 0 now) The app settings as I was still having the same issues:

edit 3:
The classic release pipeline takes the following artifact:

and then using the following steps to deploy the to the web app which updates the wwwroot

(note I need to try it once with linux, as it was being deployed to a windows machine, note the CI yaml flow wasn't working for windows either)
Edit 4:
Ultimately, it was decided to deploy our application to a Windows machine instead of Linux, as the CI release flow works. That means at the very least there is an issue of deploying correctly to Linux machines that will need to be investigated by someone, but I won't do that.

I don't find any issue in your pipeline. Testing your YAML in my pipeline, it works fine.

Please run the below Azure CLI on your local machine to deploy your web app and check if there is the same issue or not.
az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path <zip-package-path>

Update
I can reproduce your issue when app setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is 1.
Cause
According to Run your app in Azure App Service directly from a ZIP package, when you set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 1, it enables your app to run directly from a ZIP package. The files in the package are not copied to the wwwroot directory. Instead, the ZIP package itself gets mounted directly as the read-only wwwroot directory.
Solution
Change WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0 in your app settings.

Manually update in your web app: Change app settings in Environment variables


Automatically update using DevOps pipeline: Use parameter appSettings in AzureWebApp@1 task


    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: 'webAppLinux'
        appName: '$(webAppName)'
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        appSettings: '-WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE 0'


unfortunately, it did not work. I updated the original question with a picture of the app settings

Hi @Dennis.Verweij, please change WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0 in your app settings. See my detailed update above.

I've updated the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0 and also added it to the app settings parameter of the AzureWebApp@1 task. However, I get the same result of the file not being deployed correctly.

Hi @Dennis.Verweij, 1. To narrow down the issue, you can try to create a new web app and deploy to the new one. If the files still can't be uploaded to site/wwwroot folder, the issue is related to your project. If there isn't the same issue, it's related to your original web app. 2. May I know if you have created any slot in your affected web app?

I created the web app yesterday specifically to see what was going wrong. I know the project isn't incorrect as we used the release tab in Dev Ops before, and the project deploys via that manner, but not via the Yaml CI flow we're trying to transition to. There are no other slots on this specific web app.

If you still use the classic release pipeline to deploy your web app, will site/wwwroot folder be updated now? If it works, would you share the screenshots of your release pipeline's artifact settings and tasks?
